# How many sample count number for basic monitoring per period?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I need help in making sense of how many data points (SampleCount) I get in 5-minute intervals in basic monitoring.

I have basic monitoring for an EC2 instance, which means new data point is gathered every 5 minutes.

With MetricsDataQueries API, I can get data points for the metric.

I have queried to get SampleCount of data points every 5 minutes in a 10-minute period.

Data shows (10-min period):

0 min - 5 sample count
5 min - 5 sample count

I am confused now as to what this actually means. Since basic monitoring gathers data every 5 minute, I would've expected to have 1 data point per 5 minute intervals. So my expectation:

0 min - 1 sample count
5 min - 1 sample count

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't know where it's documented, but EC2 metrics are always gathered every minute, they just publish a 5 minute summary (so five metrics are published at the same time) for basic monitoring, but publish the metrics every minute as they're gathered for detailed monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

Default monitoring metrics are collected every 5 minutes but the custom monitoring metrics are collected every minute. See [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/faqs/).

> **A custom metric** can be one of the following:
>
> Standard resolution, with data having one-minute granularity
>
> High resolution, with data at a granularity of one second
>
> By default, metrics are stored at 1-minute resolution in CloudWatch. You can define a metric as high-resolution by setting the StorageResolution parameter to 1 in the PutMetricData API request. If you do not set the optional StorageResolution parameter, then CloudWatch will default to storing the metrics at 1-minute resolution.
>
> When you publish a high-resolution metric, CloudWatch stores it with a resolution of 1 second, and you can read and retrieve it with a period of 1 second, 5 seconds, 10 seconds, 30 seconds, or any multiple of 60 seconds.
>
> Custom metrics follow the same retention schedule listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Difference (one of) between detailed monitoring and basic monitoring is the frequency at which the data is published to CloudWatch. In the case of basic monitoring that is every 5 min and in the case of detailed monitoring that is every 1 minute.

Data collected is the same and the 5 min datapoint that is published in the case of basic monitoring is an aggregation of the 1 min datapoints, that's why the sample count is 5, it's an aggregation of five 1 min samples.

Below is an example of a metric before and after the detailed monitoring was enabled.

- **Before enabling** - no difference between graphing the metric at 1 min or 5 min resolution.
- **After enabling** - graphing at 1 min resolution gives you more detail.

[image: CloudWatch snapshot]